# How do I add a CSS class to only one <label> at any given time, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#custom-options label').click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('checked');
});
```

What I'm aiming to do this when I click a `<label>` it adds the class `.checked`. This works until I click another `<label>` then I have two labels with the class `.checked` ...although I only want to add this to the one I've clicked and I'd like all the rest of the `<label>`s to have the class `.uncheck`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#custom-options label').click(function(){
    $('#custom-options label.checked').removeClass('checked').addClass('uncheck');
    $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('checked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... here's the full solution:  $('#custom-options label').click(function(){
  $('.checked').removeClass('checked').addClass('uncheck');
  $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('checked');
 });

Answer (score 1):

remove the class from all the labels:

```
$('#custom-options label').click(function(){
    $('#custom-options label.checked').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).removeClass('uncheck').addClass('checked');
});
```